# Extracting a single value from a json array in sql server

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server, t-sql

I am using MS SQL server to get a search result in json format there is only ever 1 row returned in my use case but they designed this as a search tool so you can return more than one value hence the array. The issue I am having is extracting the id value from the array that is returned.

json @response (Array):

```
{"hits":[{"id":1320172,"email":"xyz@domain.eu","first_name":"IMA","last_name":"TESTERTOO","created":"2018-12-12T11:52:58+00:00","roles":["Learner"],"status":true}],"total":1}
```

I have tried a number of things but I can't seem to get the path right.

```
SET @MyUserid = JSON_QUERY(@Reponse, '$.hits[0].id')  

SET @MyUserid  =JSON_VALUE(@Reponse,'$.hits[0].id')

SET @MyUserid = JSON_QUERY(@Reponse, '$.id')
```

On most examples I have found the json is not a single line array so I feel like I am missing something there. I'm inexperienced with working with json so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `SET @MyUserid  =JSON_VALUE(@Reponse,'$.hits[0].id')` works for me, with the input you've given.

Comment: can u try --> SET @MyUserid  =JSON_VALUE(@Reponse,'$.hits.id')

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the @MyUserid  is being set to NULL. Jeroen what type of variable are you using? I am wondering if for some reason it could not be stored in a varchar(500)?

Comment: `DECLARE @reponse NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'{"hits":[{"id":1320172,"email":"xyz@domain.eu","first_name":"IMA","last_name":"TESTERTOO","created":"2018-12-12T11:52:58+00:00","roles":["Learner"],"status":true}],"total":1}'; DECLARE @myUserId INT; SET @MyUserid  =JSON_VALUE(@Reponse,'$.hits[0].id'); SELECT @myUserId;` (`@MyUserID` can be a `VARCHAR(500)` too if you like, `JSON_VALUE` returns `NVARCHAR(4000)`).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen DECLARE @myUserId INT; this was the issue I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)=
N'{"hits":[{"id":1320172,"email":"xyz@domain.eu","first_name":"IMA","last_name":"TESTERTOO","created":"2018-12-12T11:52:58+00:00","roles":["Learner"],"status":true}],"total":1}';
```

--This will return just one selected value

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.hits[0].id')
```

--This will return the *whole everything*:

```
SELECT A.total
      ,B.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH(hits nvarchar(max) AS JSON, total int) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.hits) 
WITH(id int
    ,email nvarchar(max)
    ,first_name nvarchar(max)
    ,last_name nvarchar(max)
    ,created nvarchar(max)
    ,roles nvarchar(max) AS JSON
    ,[status] bit) B
```